# Is web-browser to Excel interprocess communication possible

Tags: excel

Is is possible to write a browser plugin (one that requires the user to install something is OK) that would allow interprocess communication between the browser and a running instance of Excel (on Windows)? For example, suppose I want the user to be able to click something within their browser, and then have a piece of text drop into the selected cell in Excel as a result. This is certainly possible to do with a regular desktop application and Excel, but I'm not sure if it is possible with a browser, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible.  I know that in the Mozilla Plugin API you can instantiate COM objects in windows.  I believe you can communicate with Excel through COM so I think you should be ok.  Take a look around for XPCom and the Gecko Plugin API for Mozilla.

Usually you can do these things because the system trusts your app due to installation.  The install and the extensions API often give you a lot of access to lower system layers because of the trust factor since the user has to explicitly allow it.

**EDIT**: removed NSAPI - it's actually NPAPI.  Good catch.

Comment: SB - how does NSAPI apply to browser plugins? My impression was that NSAPI was for writing web-server plugins.